# Python: How to call a child class's overridden method

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have got few classes which extend each other. And then I have another class which calls an overridden method `_draw(self.turtle)`.

Class structure:

```
class Canvas:
    def __init__(self,w,h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.visibleObjects = []
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.screen = turtle.Screen()
        self.screen.setup(width=self.width,height=self.height)
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def draw(self,gObject):
        gObject.setCanvas(self)
        gObject.setVisible(True)
        self.turtle.up()
        self.screen.tracer(0)
        gObject._draw(self.turtle)
        self.screen.tracer(1)
        self.addShape(gObject)

class GeometricObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lineColor = 'black'
        self.lineWidth = 1
        self.visible = False
        self.myCanvas = None

    // setters and getters

class Shape(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, fillColor = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.fillColor = fillColor

        def setFill(self, aturtle):
            aturtle.begin_fill()
            aturtle.down()
            aturtle.color(self.fillColor)


class Polygon(Shape):
    def __init__(self, cornerPoints, color, lineColor, lineWidth):
        super().__init__(color)
        self.cornerPoints = cornerPoints

    def _draw(self, aturtle):
        // Start Drawing

class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, threePoints, fillColor = None, lineColor = None, lineWidth = None):
        super().__init__(threePoints, fillColor, lineColor, lineWidth)
        if (lineColor is not None):
            self.lineColor = lineColor

        if(lineWidth is not None):
            self.lineWidth = lineWidth

        def _draw(self, aturtle):
            if (self.fillColor is not None):
                self.setFill(aturtle)
                aturtle.up()
                Polygon._draw(self, aturtle)
                aturtle.end_fill() 

myCanvas = Canvas(800,600)
triangle = Triangle([Point(-50, -10), Point(150,25), Point(50,50)], "red", "yellow")
myCanvas.draw(triangle)
```

When `myCanvas.draw(triangle)` is called, it executes the draw method in the Canvas class. On the 6th line of draw method, I am calling the actual class's _draw method `gObject._draw(self.turtle)`. When I debugged at this point, gObject was of type Triangle. So when this line of code is executed I expect the control to go to Triangle's _draw(). However the control moves to Polygon's _draw() and the control never comes to Triangle's _draw().

I do not understand why is it executing Polygon's _draw() ? Can somebody please help me out here ? Is there something missing in the code.

p.s: I have multiple geometric objects class like Rectangle, Square which extend Polygon etc.

Comment: you have wrong indentions in triangle so you don't override `_draw()`

Comment: BTW. Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`

Comment: @furas: I checked the indentations in the code. Shift tabbed everything and then tabbed the lines to again re-indent it. Still it doesn't call the child class method
I usually code in Java, new to Python. So just to shorten the length of the question, I mistakenly use // instead of #.

Comment: check your code in question - _draw() is inside `Triangle.__init__`  - it is not `Triange._draw()`

Comment: Wow. I spent half an hour on this. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your indentions are wrong. For instance:

```
class Shape(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, fillColor = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.fillColor = fillColor

        def setFill(self, aturtle):
            aturtle.begin_fill()
            aturtle.down()
            aturtle.color(self.fillColor)
```

does NOT define a `Shape.setFill` method, but a `setFill` function that exists only in the `Shape.__init__` method. So, for the same reason, the following code does not override the `_draw` method:

```
class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, threePoints, fillColor = None, lineColor = None, lineWidth = None):
        super().__init__(threePoints, fillColor, lineColor, lineWidth)
        if (lineColor is not None):
            self.lineColor = lineColor

        if(lineWidth is not None):
            self.lineWidth = lineWidth

        def _draw(self, aturtle):
            if (self.fillColor is not None):
                self.setFill(aturtle)
                aturtle.up()
                Polygon._draw(self, aturtle)
                aturtle.end_fill()
```

For the "trivia", note that Python typing does not work as Java's or other's. In particular, there is no cast, unless you explicitly define it.
So if you define `Mother` and `Daughter` as follows:

```
class Mother:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def printClass(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

class Daughter(Mother):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

there is no direct way to get `"Mother"` printed when calling `printClass` on a `Daughter` object.

In Java, something like:

```
(Mother)Daughter.printClass();
```

would print `"Mother"`, but you cannot do such things in Python.

In other words, a variable can be reassigned an object with a different type, but there is no way to change the type of a variable without reassigning it.

By the way, a workaround would be defining a `castToMother` method inside of the `Daughter` class, or something like this.

The point of this explanation, is to have you sure that if you know that your `triangle` object is of type `Triangle`, there is no way that `triangle._draw` would call `Polygon._draw`.